# Set Android Studio layout for user feedback

Tags: android, controls, alignment

I need to design question and get users feedback as per below design. please advise what is the best android studio layout to use. shall I use table layout , or use vertical layout for different questions, and then use Horizontal Layout for each question text and radio buttons.?

NB.  Layout is RTL.
     Target is 16

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) is designed for this purpose, as it is much cleaner and more readable.